# What was the meaning of the word "Guedena"?

Tags: ancient, sumerian, akkadian

According to Wikipedia, Guedena, (also, "Gu-Edin", or "Gu'edena") was a fertile plain in Sumer.

[Guedena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu-Edin)

> Gu-Edin (also transcribed "Gu'edena" or "Guedena") was a fertile plain in Sumer, in modern-day Iraq. It lay between Umma and Lagash

[Photo by Umma2350 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu-Edin#/media/File:Gu-Edin.jpg)
[image: Location of Gu-Edin, between Umma and Lagash in Sumer.]

**Question**

Is the definition of Guedena known?

Comment: Surely the commonest meanings of "gu" in Sumerian are "side" or "river bank"?

Comment: That's written  gu₂/gú, not  gu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name was written literally GU-EDIN (or GU-EDIN-NA) in cuneiform. Radau suggests that GU here means Akkadian *mātu* "flat land, field" and EDIN means *bamātu* "open country, plain". (He also relates it to Hebrew *bamoth* "high places".) In other words, the name literally meant "the open fields".

EDIN meaning "plain" is pretty standard (though it's usually equated with the borrowed Akkadian *edinu* "steppe"), but this is a meaning of GU I haven't seen before. Still, it makes more sense than the usual meaning of GU ("net").

Source: Radau's [*Early Babylonian History Down to the End of the Fourth Dynasty of Ur*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Early_Babylonian_History_Down_to_the_End/rgnGAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=gu-edin&pg=PA87&printsec=frontcover), page 86 onwards. The book is from 1900, so take it with many grains of salt, but I haven't found anything more recent specifically discussing the GU part of this name.

Comment: So is he suggesting that the name would actually have been spoken as _Mātu Bamātu_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It seems so, but I think I must be understanding him wrong because a name consisting of two separate nouns in the nominative is very odd. Or perhaps our understanding of Akkadian syntax has just advanced since 1900.

Comment: (Well, spoken that way in an Akkadian context at least. Presumably in a Sumerian context it would have been straightforwardly _gu-edina_.)